# XCode 4 with Git/Github, can't commit images

Tags: iphone, git, ipad, github, xcode4

Source codes files are getting committed but images are not.

Error message
error:pathscpec '' did not match any file(s) known to git.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XCode release notes mention that there is a problem commiting binary files right now. They suggest that after you get that error you should go to the command line and do "git commit".