# Committing within Xcode (using Git) any image files?

Tags: xcode, git

Right now, if I press Option-Command-c to commit the whole project, any image files are not committed... I even tried a folder `trytry`:

```
MyProj
|--Images
|--MyProj.xcodeproj
|--MyProj
   |--trytry
```

so, images files inside `MyProj/Images` cannot be added or committed, and also image files in the `trytry` folder are the same too...

There was a question on StackOverflow about Xcode not able to commit image, that there was a bug:

[XCode 4 with Git/Github, can't commit images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529307/xcode-4-with-git-github-cant-commit-images)

but I don't see any bug (no error message), but just that there is no way to add or commit?  Besides, the bug was 1 year old... should be fixed by now -- after all, Xcode is just using Git, not implementing Git... so shouldn't be any technical difficulties?

Comment: Do image files show up if you open Terminal and run `git status` from the MyProj directory?  This could be a .gitignore issue.

Comment: that's true... it doesn't show any file that needs attention... so it may be a git ignore file issue... just that there is no `.gitignore` file any where... not in the proj, and not up above, all the way to the home folder, so... could it be an ignore done else where?

Comment: Try `find . -name .gitignore -type f` from the project root directory.  If you get any output (I expect that you'll see the line "./.gitignore"), then you have a .gitignore.

Comment: nope, didn't find any... I used `ls .gitignore` before in the project root directory and then `cd ..` and try again unless I tried at the `~` directory and still nope

Comment: Turns out the images were added using "Add Group" and then "Add files"... it appears as a folder in the folder tree, but then the files were not copied from else where but just "referenced"... there isn't an Images folder either... I am checking out how do add a folder within Xcode and add files (as in copying them)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, turns out that, it appears as a new folder and this folder has files in it (inside Xcode), but in fact, if you look at the File System (using Finder, for example), you will see no folder and possibly no files... the folder in Xcode is actually a Group, and the files may or may not be in the project folder... depending whether they are referenced or copied over when you choose "Add files".

You can get more info here: [Why in Xcode, Groups can be created, but not real folders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10368101/why-in-xcode-groups-can-be-created-but-not-real-folders)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled forever with the same problem. I had image .png files in the project that could not be added to version control ("add" button dimmed out), but found a solution.

This was because of the method I used to add the files to the project. Like yours, they were in a group folder in the XCode tree. I had made a real folder with the same name on the disk, put the files there, then added them to the group folder using the "Add Files..." popup menu, without clicking "copy files to destination". They were added to the group, but to my dismay, without any option to add them to version control afterwards! The issue is, if you bring files in that way, XCode doesn't think it "owns" the files. It just linked  to them. It won't let you do version control.

Here is how to fix it:

1. **Associate the group folder (in XCode project tree) with the real folder on the disk**: Select the XCode group folder, open the file inspector in the right pane, and click on the super small icon that looks like a little window, just below and to the right of the "Relative to Group". In the popup, navigate to your real folder. This will associate the group with the real folder location on disk. Now whatever you put in that group, XCode will ask you to copy in the real disk folder (and vice versa, whatever you put in the disk folder shows up in the XCode group).
2. **Get rid of the old file links**. In Finder, drag all the files out of the folder that you could not add to version control to another location (e.g. desktop). Now go back to XCode, and delete all the old files references (now showing red) in your group folder.
3. **Now add the files back into XCode the correct way**. Right click the group, click Add Files..., and navigate to the files you just moved. Or just drag all the files back from finder on the XCode group folder. Make sure you check "copy items to destination..." in the popup that appears. This time files will be copied to your associated folder on the disk, and XCode knows it owns them.

The files can now be added to source control. You can delete your extra copies on the desktop.