# Why in Xcode, Groups can be created, but not real folders?

Tags: xcode

When doing iOS programming, it is interesting that in Xcode (4.3.2), we can create groups, such as a group call `Images`, and add files to it (either as a link or choose "Copy items into group's folder").  So it looks like a real folder in the navigator, and it even mentions "copy into ... group's **folder**", but in fact there is no folder.  All added files are in the same location as the `.m` and `.h` files.

Why would we want Groups, but not real folder?  Is there advantage of Groups over the use of a folder?

Comment: at least when I right click on the project's folder, there is a choice for "New Group" but not "New Folder"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

> Note: In Xcode 10, the default behavior now creates a linked folder when you create a new group. The information below still applies otherwise.

The recommended way to organize files is via groups, because it's more flexible than creating directories, and allows you to create complex file hierarchies while maintaining a totally different file hierarchy on the file system. It's simply an organization tool. That said, it is possible to turn groups into folder references, or create them initially as folder references.

Furthermore, using groups instead of folder references gives you greater flexibility if you need to change where things are in the file system - say you have a common folder of code that you use in a bunch of different projects. Groups allow you to organize the files inside of  projects as if they were in the projects, while still maintaining one copy of the code in a central location. And yes, you can do this with folder references as well, but groups are much more flexible if you later want to add other things to the same group but don't want them to be added to that common folder.

If you want to link a group to a folder, click on the group in the project file tree and hit command+option+1. Below the drop down that'll say something like "Path: Relative to Group" on the right, there's a little white square with a grey border around it kinda icon next to the word "none". Clicking on this and then selecting/creating a folder will bind the group to the folder.

[image: folder reference]

Furthermore, when you drag a folder into Xcode, it will ask you if you want it to be a group or a folder reference:

[image: adding a folder reference]

Comment: But "bind the group to the folder" is not the same as "create folder references". The latter is special: it copies the *folder* into the build app.

Comment: However it is a pain when you want to look for a class in finder/svn and the directory structure is completely different

Comment: @htafoya I definitely agree. On the other hand, if you're reorganizing a bunch of files using groups instead of folders, there's less opportunity for merge conflicts in your actual source code since the files themselves don't move. There are absolutely important tradeoffs to consider.

Comment: I know some people prefer this style, and I'm sure it's great in theory. In practice... not so much. For instance my Xcode is currently crashing when I move things from one group to another. Hard to paint yourself as clever or in any way optimal if I can't organise my files at all

Answer (score 49):

This is a pet peeve of mine.

I recommend, making the folder in your file system, where you have your project files, then drag that folder into Xcode where you want the group.  It will act like any other group, but now be linked to the folder on the file system.  Adding files to that group in Xcode now adds them to the folder in the file system.

Much cleaner way of working and helps when locating files in big projects.  Keeps git cleaner too.

**Update for Xcode 9:**

Once you have the groups in Xcode matching the directory structure on disk, moving a file from one group to another in Xcode will now move the file correctly on disk to match.

Comment: I just wonder why Xcode does not start out as just using folders instead of groups?

Comment: Yep, it keeps Git cleaner :)

Comment: Yeh noticed in Xcode 9 using folders for groups is now the default too

Answer (score 10):

There is a **Command Line Tool - "synx"**
 available in github that do exactly what you need.

It reorganizes Xcode project folder in finder to match Xcode groups in project.

You can find it here:
https://github.com/venmo/synx

**UPDATE**: XCode 9 supports this feature by default. So, no need to use other tools anymore!

Comment: if you forgot to create folders while adding new group, then this is **the best** way to convert xcode groups into folder system